# How to make local environment same for Do File Editor as for Command/Results (to use tempfiles)

Tags: environment-variables, stata, local, environment

How can I make the environment be the same for the Do File editor and the Command/Results?

What I mean is this: if one runs code from the Do File editor that defines a local (`local localname localvalue`), then that local is not accessible  when typing in the `Command` window. How can I make the environment (meaning the environment as it refers to locals) the same for both the Do File editor and the Command window?

The practical reason I want to do this is that I use lots of tempfiles in my code. If I have hundreds or thousands of lines of code written up in the Do File editor, I need to copy and paste all of them into the Command window in order to access the individual tempfiles when testing out individual lines of code in the Command window. This is a bit tedious to have to do over and over.

As an example, suppose that we run this code from the Do File editor:

```
sysuse auto2, clear
tempfile auto
save `auto'
```

Then we cannot access `auto` from the Command window. Is it possible to change a setting in Stata that will in fact allow us to access `auto`?

Comment: You can't, in totality, and this is a feature. Otherwise this is what `global`s allow. There is also the `include` command, which is documented, and the `c_local` command, which definitely isn't. The idea behind `c_local` seems to be that if you find it, work out what it does, and know that it is dangerous, then you're a Stata programmer fit to use it. `c_local` has been mentioned on Statalist from time to time.

Comment: Thanks you. Is it possible to use `c_local` with tempfiles?

Comment: You can push a copy of the filename into the caller space.

Comment: How would one push a copy of the filename to the caller space? And, related, is it possible to create global tempfile?

Comment: These are similar questions. I'll answer the second. `tempfile` doesn't create a file; it creates the name that you could use for a new file in your space. So, `tempfile foo` puts the name of a new file in a local macro `foo`. Although I am not sure, the principle seems to imply that you could copy that name to a `global`  and you would might well be safe in using that `global` elsewhere. I have to comment generally that I am very unclear why you want to do this and how far this is all good strategy. At worst, you might be lining yourself for some really horrible bugs.

Comment: Disclaimer: You have been asking about this on Twitter, but I don't ever read everything there or comment one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks very much. A few comments. 1. The users on Twitter said that one solution is to skip the `tempfile` approach altogether and instead save normal files and them use `rm` at the end to remove them. This seems like it could be a good solution. Nobody mentioned `c_local` or `include`, both of which I wasn't previously aware of and are good to know about. 2. Thanks for helping me better understand what `tempfile` is doing. I will have to look into the `global` version.

Comment: 3. About why I want to do this. I think one analogue is how R has variables that can store data, say data frames. One can access these variables either through R's analogues of the Do File Editor and Command prompt, and they don't disappear when switching between the two. In Stata, I often have multiple datasets floating around that I am working on (merging, etc.) and I find it convenient to quickly load them with `use `tempfilename', clear`. Sometimes these tempfiles are defined in the Do File editor.

Comment: 3 (cont). Say that I have 5,000 lines of code in the Do File editor and this code contains dozens of tempfiles. My workflow involves running all 5,000 lines of code contained in the Do File editor and then switching to the Command prompt to work on the 5,001st line of code. Sometimes I need to access tempfiles from the 5,000 lines of code in order to figure out the 5,001st line or even just to run summary stats, etc. The way Stata is set up, I have to copy and paste and run all 5,000 lines into the Command prompt in order to access the tempfiles. This is what I am trying to work around.

Comment: 3 (cont). And in general I find it clunky to save dozens of files physically and then later delete them, but this is just my opinion. I find tempfiles to be a nicer solution.

Comment: Well, thanks, but you can't win. I think that's too much detail to hold in my head at once and if it's crucial it should go in the question. I doubt that I can give more time to this but it's wide open to anyone else, except that at the moment very few people seem to be following the Stata tag here. Guess what: Statalist is where most of the Stata questions are asked and answered.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and I appreciate the above comments! Maybe I'll ask the question on Statalist.

Comment: As an update. Thanks for mentioning the `include` command. I now see that this is exactly what I need, particularly given that the Do File Editor allows one to run a snippet of code using `Execute selection (include)`, which is perfect for me.